# Ant emma debug install test does not recognize org.mock.Mocktio

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant

I want to get the code coverage report for my Andriod tests.

I am running this command

```
 ant emma debug install test
```

This works and the Tests pass and the coverage report is generated when I am not using Mockito to mock a class.

But if I run it with Mockito ant emma gives a error

```
error: package org.mockito does not exist
```

The test with Mockito pass when I run them without any coverage.

Are there any special settings or jars I need to include before running ant emma for Tests that use Mockito ?

IDE : intellij 14,
Jars used : dex-maker 1.0 , dex-maker-mockito 1.0 , mockito 1.9.5,

Answer (score 0):

For the `ant emma debug install test` to work with Mockito

put the `dex-maker 1.0 , dex-maker-mockito 1.0 , mockito 1.9.5 jar` files in the

libs folder of your Andriod project.

If you are restrating your coverage report use `ant clean emma debug install test`